# Ionic 4 Manual Override of ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-select

Hi I need 'select from list' functionality on a form but with the ability to enter a value manually if needed.  I've been trying ion-select but there doesn't seem to be a way to have a manual override.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

For example

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>kitlist testy</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Lens</ion-label>
      <ion-select placeholder="Select One">
          <ion-select-option value="f">Female</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="m">Male</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName='lens'></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>


</form>
</ion-content>
```

will give 
[image]

I want the user to be able to add their own value - which I will then store.

Thanks

Following Sergey's very helpful answer I have tried getting this to work and I'm stuck at inputAlert.onDidDismiss which gives me

> Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Here's the code which I have adjusted for my use case:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { AlertController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-kitlist",
  templateUrl: "./kitlist.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./kitlist.page.scss"]
})
export class KitlistPage implements OnInit {
  kitlist = ["lens1", "lens2", "Custom"];
  currentLens: any;
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private alertController: AlertController
  ) {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      lens: ""
    });

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log("submit");
  }

  selectChanged(selectedLens) {
    if (selectedLens === "Custom") {
      this.inputCustomLensValue();
    } else {
      this.currentLens = selectedLens;
    }
  }

  async inputCustomLensValue() {
    const inputAlert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: "Enter your custom lens:",
      inputs: [{ type: "text", placeholder: "type in" }],
      buttons: [{ text: "Cancel" }, { text: "Ok" }]
    });

    inputAlert.onDidDismiss(data => {
      let customLensName: string = data.data.values[0];
      if (customLensName) {
        let indexFound = this.kitlist.findIndex(
          lens => lens === customLensName
        );
        if (indexFound === -1) {
          this.kitlist.push(customLensName);
          this.currentLens = customLensName;
        } else {
          this.currentLens = this.kit[indexFound];
        }
      }
    });
    await inputAlert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? What component have you used now? Do you need a search feature on the drop-down select?

Comment: and please share all the code that you created?

Comment: Hi I don't need a search feature.  If the required values are not in the drop down (I will have got them from a DB)  I need the user to be able to add a 'new' value. I'll add some info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ion-select under the hood uses alert controller, I would leverage it directly and I would have a couple of alerts working together here:

In your template:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Hair Color</ion-label>
    <ion-button slot="end" (click)="selectColors()">{{ currentOptionLabel }}
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
```

You can style ion-button according to your needs.

Now in your ts file we can import Alert Controller and have 2 of them: one for selecting premade options and one that we will create input type of alert in case our user wants to add custom value.

I am not using button's handler's methods here to make sure Angular can pick up all the data changes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.css'],
})
export class HomePage {

  public colorOptions: Array<{type: string, label: string, value: string}>

  public currentColorOptionIndex: number;

  public currentOptionLabel: string;

  constructor(public alertController: AlertController) {
    this.currentColorOptionIndex = 1;
    this.colorOptions = [
      {
        type: "radio",
        label: "Custom",
        value: "Custom"
      },
      {
        type: "radio",
        label: "Brown",
        value: "Brown",
      },
      {
        type: "radio",
        label: "Dark",
        value: "Dark",
      }
    ]
    this.currentOptionLabel = this.colorOptions[this.currentColorOptionIndex].label;
  }

  async selectColors() {
    const radioAlert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Prompt!',
      inputs: this.colorOptions as any,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary'
        }, {
          text: 'Ok'
        }
      ]
    });

    await radioAlert.present();

    radioAlert.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
      let selectedValue = data.data.values;
      if (selectedValue === 'Custom') {
        this.inputCustomColorValue()
      };
      this.currentColorOptionIndex = this.colorOptions.findIndex(option => option.value == selectedValue)
      this.currentOptionLabel = this.colorOptions[this.currentColorOptionIndex].label;
    })
  }

  async inputCustomColorValue() {
    const inputAlert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Enter your custom color:',
      inputs: [
        {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'type in'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary'
        }, {
          text: 'Ok',
        }
      ]
    });

    await inputAlert.present();

    inputAlert.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
      let customValue = data.data.values[0];
      let indexFound = this.colorOptions.findIndex(option => option.value == customValue)
      if (indexFound !== -1) {
        this.currentColorOptionIndex = indexFound
      } else {
        this.colorOptions.push(
          {
            type: 'radio',
            label: customValue,
            value: customValue,
          }
        )
        this.currentColorOptionIndex = this.colorOptions.length - 1;
      };
      this.currentOptionLabel = this.colorOptions[this.currentColorOptionIndex].label;
    })
  }

}
```

Updated: added the fact that now in latest Ionic versions (compared to Stackblitz that uses old 4 beta) onDidDismiss hook returns Promise and requires onDidDismiss.then((data) => {}) syntax vs onDidDismiss((data => {})

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after  - thankyou.  It'll take me a while to work out how it works! - Thanks again

Comment: Hey glad this sets you on the right path:) feel free to ping me here if you have a question. Also I compiled this pretty quickly - so there might be edge cases. But happy to help turn this into a useful UX widget

Comment: @Townheadbluesboy hey man, I actually updated this answer and maybe the second implementation is better and cleaner!

Comment: Hi Sergey - Stuck at onDidDismiss - code above thanks Kevin.

Comment: inputAlert.onDidDismiss((data)  Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Comment: interesting, can you share which version of Ionic you are using? 3.9.4 (Ionic 3) or 4.11.x?

Comment: $ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.5 (C:\Users\Kevin\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.2.2
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Comment: I'm going to try and build it from your stackblitz .  I'll post later  - off to the gym.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a bug. this method definitely returns data;/

Comment: Hi Sergey - which version of Ionic are your running?  I've just copied your stackblitz and got the same error.

Comment: hmm just checked this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-cb2wbk - no errors. Can you share which stackblitz.com gives you error?

Comment: Just updated ionic to 4.11.7. Created a new project copied homepage from  stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-cb2wbk -

Comment: Still get src/app/home/home.page.ts(88,29): error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.  Also ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts:42:7 - error TS2322: Type '{ type: string; label: string; value: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'AlertInput[]'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204426/discussion-between-sergey-rudenko-and-townheadbluesboy).

Comment: Hi Does anyone know if there is a new of doing this?  Using either Ionic 5 or Angular components?  I still need to be able to manually override a select.